# Reading a file from a specific point problem

Tags: c, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

I'm using TCP server/client C application to send a file from server to client. File must be sent in parts (one part per one connection). I successfully send file from server to client, that's not the problem. The problem is with the one part per connection, getting the right part to be sent. I'm using fseek() to find the size of whole file and divided it by 4. That's the size of chunk that I want to be sent to client. A problem persists because I get more chunk than I actually expect.

```
// Retrieve file size
fSize = fileSize(filePtr);

// How much bytes to send
if (fSize >= 4)
{
    leftToSend = fSize / SEND_DENOM;
}
else
{
    leftToSend = fSize;
}

int fpOffset = leftToSend * (partToSend - 1);

fseek(filePtr, fpOffset, SEEK_SET);

int i = 0;
char cFromFile;

while(leftToSend != 0 || feof(filePtr))
{

    cFromFile = fgetc(filePtr);
    dataBuffer[i++] = cFromFile;

    leftToSend--;
    bytesSent++;

    if (strlen(dataBuffer) == (BUFFER_SIZE - 1) || leftToSend == 0)
    {
        // Send message to client
        iResult = sendto(clientSocket,                      
                            dataBuffer,                     
                            strlen(dataBuffer),             
                            0,                              
                            (SOCKADDR *)&clientAddress,     
                            sizeof(clientAddress)); 

        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("sendto failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(clientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            ExitThread(100);
        }

        // Set whole buffer to zero
        memset(dataBuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

        i = 0;
    }

}
```

Find file size function:

```
unsigned long long int fileSize (FILE* filePtr)
{
    unsigned long long int fSize = 0;

    fseek(filePtr, 0, SEEK_END);
    fSize = ftell(filePtr);
    rewind(filePtr);

    return fSize;
}
```

Example (How it should look):

This is a problem...

1. chunk - This_
2. chunk - is_a_
3. chunk - probl
4. chunk - em...

And this is something I get:

1. chunk - This_is_a
2. chunk - is_a_prob
3. chunk - problem..
4. chunk - em...

where _ represents blank space

Comment: So far I can't identify any obvious alarms from a quick oversight. Please post the sendto function or at least explain what it does.

Comment: You are not writing a string terminator into `dataBuffer[ ]` and so `strlen` will fail. Also what is the `|| feof(filePtr)` for? Why do you want to read forever if you already have an read error? You know the size of the file, so just count the bytes.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm assuming the author initialised the buffer to zero. Also there is a memset to zero in the if

Comment: @john ok, then the end condition is `strlen(dataBuffer) == (BUFFER_SIZE - 1)`, not the chunk size. `leftToSend` is not reset.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, the buffer is initialised to zero. That's something I forgot to copy from source. leftToSend should not be reseted as it is the end of transmission.

Comment: @AleksaArsic what is SEND_DENOM?

Comment: @John A number which divides the length of file

Comment: @AleksaArsic I know but how much is it?

Comment: @John As I mentioned in the question it is 4.

Comment: Understood. Well look, the code seems fine to me in terms of splitting the contents of a file into chunks and sending it to the client is defined more or less correctly. The only reason for there to be a problem is that the file you get from the server has bad data or there are thread clashes

Comment: Also, what would normally be defined in the partToSend variable?

Comment: Also, I'm a bit unclear on the chunk size. Is it 4 bytes that you want to send at a time? Or 5 bytes as per your correct example? Or is it BUFFER_SIZE?

Comment: @John partToSend is a variable that determines which portion of the file will be read. First, second, third or fourth. By my example it is 5 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments you've mentioned, try the following code.
I'll assume you calculate the leftToSend variable correctly.

```
while((leftToSend >= 0) || feof(filePtr))
{
    cFromFile = fgetc(filePtr);
    dataBuffer[i] = cFromFile;

    i++;
    leftToSend--;

    if ((i >= (BUFFER_SIZE - 1)) || (0 == leftToSend) || (i >= (SEND_DENOM + 1)))
    {
        // Send message to client
        iResult = sendto(clientSocket,                      
                         dataBuffer,                     
                         i,             
                         0,                              
                         (SOCKADDR *)&clientAddress,     
                         sizeof(clientAddress)); 

        if (SOCKET_ERROR == iResult)
        {
            printf("sendto failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(clientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            ExitThread(100);
        }

        // Set whole buffer to zero
        memset(dataBuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

        bytesSent += i;
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. Adding

    if(cFromFile == '\n') leftToSend--;

to the body of the while loop after getting the value of cFromFile solved my problem. Apparently I had some problems with win32 representation of new line.